# How can I pass data from one api endpoint to the other api endpoint in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on an react app. This has to api endpoint `/dispensing` and `/overview` from dispensing we get some data that need to be passed to `/overview` endpoint when component mounts show that when user logged in it should show some data.
For that I am fetching the data from `/dispensing` and store it redux store and inside the component I passed it to `/overview` but it shows error that `values is not defined` but it is available in when I `console.log`.
And when I make refresh after that it works fine. I have no idea why.

Here is my code

```
const DispensingIncidents = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const {
    getFilterData,
    dispensingData,
    getOverviewData,
    location,
    history,
    getAnalysis,
  } = props;

  const [timeSpan, setTimeSpan] = React.useState("monthly");
  const [year, setYear] = React.useState(2020);
  const [tabValue, setTabValue] = React.useState(0);
  const [spanData, setSpanData] = React.useState([]);
  const [dataType, setDataType] = React.useState("");
  const [dataTo, setDataTo] = React.useState("");
  const [dataFrom, setDataFrom] = React.useState("");

  // eslint-disable-next-line
  const [overViewDataType, setOverViewDataType] = React.useState("");

  const {
    loading,
    duration,
    period,
    type,
    dispensingOverviewData,
    overviewDataLoading,
    incidenceAnalysisData,
    analysisDataLoading,
  } = dispensingData;
  const { count } = dispensingOverviewData;
  const { monthly } = duration;
  useEffect(() => {
    history.replace({
      pathname: location.pathname,
      search: `?year=${year}&period=${timeSpan}`,
    });
    setYear(year);
    setTimeSpan(timeSpan);
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [year, timeSpan]);

  /**
   *  This updates on Year given
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    getFilterData(year);
  }, [getFilterData, year]);
  // console.log("DispesningDuration", monthly[0]);    <--- this gives the data 
  useEffect(() => {
    getOverviewData(
      Object.keys(period)[3],
      monthly[0].period.to,         <--- Here it says [0] is not defined
      monthly[0].period.from,
      Object.keys(type)[0]
    );

    setTimeSpan(Object.keys(period)[3]);
    setDataFrom(monthly[0].period.from);
    setDataTo(monthly[0].period.to);
    setDataType(Object.keys(type)[0]);
  }, [getOverviewData, period, monthly, type]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getAnalysis(
      count[0].key,
      Object.keys(period)[3],
      monthly[0].period.from,
      monthly[0].period.to,
      Object.keys(type)[0],
      1
    );
    setOverViewDataType(count[0].key);
  }, [count, getAnalysis, period, type, monthly]);

  /**
   * GET query from url search param
   *  @usage query.get("year")
   */
  function useQuery() {
    return new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  }
  const query = useQuery();
  const time = query.get("period");
  useEffect(() => {
    if (time === "yearly") {
      const yearlyData = duration["yearly"];
      setSpanData(yearlyData);
    } else if (time === "weekly") {
      const weeklyData = duration["weekly"];
      setSpanData(weeklyData);
    } else if (time === "quarterly") {
      const quarterlyData = duration["quarterly"];
      setSpanData(quarterlyData);
    } else if (time === "monthly") {
      const monthlyData = duration["monthly"];
      setSpanData(monthlyData);
    } else if (time === "6 months") {
      const halfYearlyData = duration["half-yearly"];
      setSpanData(halfYearlyData);
    }
  }, [time, duration]);

  /**
   *
   * @param {*} event
   * @param {*} newValue
   * on tab change
   */

  // eslint-disable-next-line
  const handleTabChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setTabValue(newValue);
  };

  /**
   * Year change
   * @param {*} event
   */
  const handleYearChange = (event) => {
    setYear(event.target.value);
    setTimeSpan(query.get("period"));
  };

  /**
   * Span change
   * @param {*} event
   */
  const handleSpanChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setTimeSpan(value);
  };

  const handleSpanTabChange = (data) => {
    setDataTo(data.period.to);
    setDataFrom(data.period.from);
    getOverviewData(time, data.period.to, data.period.from, dataType);
  };
  const handleDataTypeChange = (event) => {
    setDataType(event.target.value);
    getOverviewData(time, dataTo, dataFrom, event.target.value);
  };

  const handleOverViewClick = (data) => {
    getAnalysis(data, time.toLowerCase(), dataFrom, dataTo, dataType, 1);
  };
```

Comment: have you tried to check `monthly` length? try this and i guess you shouldn't see error: `monthly.length > 0 && getOverviewData(your arguments);`

Comment: My guess is that on the initial render `monthly` is undefined since your redux state hasn't populated yet, and that later the console log works because it is in the function body of your component and is asynchronously populated later when you click to inspect it in the console. You should guard against undefined values in your initial render.

Comment: @HosseinAhmadi I tried this but it did not work

Comment: @adityakumar I've checked and noticed you used `monthly[0]` a few line later. check if the location of error has changed so you need to put all your useEffect in a condition scope to run if `monthly` length is greater than 0